# SQLAlchemy and UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, encoding, sqlalchemy

I'm getting

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when I pass text coming from a MySQL database, which I am accessing using SQLAlchemy, to this function:

```
re.compile(ur"<([^>]+)>", flags=re.UNICODE).sub(u" ", s)
```

The database encoding is utf-8 and I am even passing the encoding to the create_engine function of SQLAlchemy.

**Edit:**
This is how I am querying the database:

```
doc = session.query(Document).get(doc_id)
s = doc.title
```

By suggestion, I passed s.decode('utf-8') to `sub` . The error above disappeared, but I get a different error for a different document:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 449: invalid continuation byte
```

The database table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `link_idx` (`link`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4127834 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can we see some more code? Where does `s` come from? Would `s.decode('utf8')` fix things?

Comment: @MartijnPieters adding s.decode('utf-8') fixes the error for that particular document, but if I try to get a different document from the database I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 449: invalid continuation byte . So, same error, different character.

Comment: No, that's a different error (one decodes from ascii, the other from utf-8). That means that the second document is not UTF-8 data *at all*. Which is why we want to see where `s` comes from.

Comment: Next question: how is the `title` field defined in your schema?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've added the table info to the post.

Comment: The problem may not be sql alchemy. Check that Mysql's encoding is really UTF-8 in the table level. (It helps if you have a GUI tool like `mysql-admin`)

Comment: @BorrajaX Sequel Pro shows the table encoding as utf-8

Comment: I had to follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737776/5272567) steps

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The `title` column was being returned by SQLAlchemy as a `str` and not `Unicode`.
I thought adding `encoding='utf8'` as an argument to `create_engine` would take care of this, however, the right way to do it is to pass it in the database URI: `mysql://me@myserver/mydatabase?charset=utf8` .

Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: I just get `invalid connection option "charset"` =/

Comment: This was so helpful! I hope this gets addressed in SQLAlchemy itself.

Comment: Dou you know if this works for ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server using MSSQL+PyODBC and `odbc_connect`?

Answer (score 0):

For me, my database was the wrong encoding. I had to follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737776/5272567) steps to change postgresql encoding to utf8.