# PG::Error: ERROR: new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have installed `postgresql-9.2.4` from the source, now in rails app when I execute:

`rake db:create` command I get:

```
$ bin/rake db:create RAILS_ENV="test"
PG::Error: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)
HINT:  Use the same encoding as in the template database, or use template0 as template.
: CREATE DATABASE "verticals_test" ENCODING = 'unicode'
/home/vagrant/my-project/.gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:652:in `exec
....
bin/rake:16:in `load'
bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"my_db", "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"my_user", "password"=>"my_password"}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Ok, below steps resolved the problem:

1. First, we need to drop template1. Templates can’t be dropped, so we first modify it so t’s an ordinary database:

   `UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = FALSE WHERE datname = 'template1';`
2. Now we can drop it:

   `DROP DATABASE template1;`
3. Now its time to create database from template0, with a new default encoding:

   `CREATE DATABASE template1 WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UNICODE';`
4. Now modify template1 so it’s actually a template:

   `UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template1';`
5. Now switch to template1 and VACUUM FREEZE the template:

   `\c template1`

   `VACUUM FREEZE;`

Problem should be resolved.

Comment: @tokhi This is working solution. I'm not to much familiar for posgresql but my only small step 0:`sudo -u postgres psql postgres` for debian or similar OS.

Comment: I prefer the locales solution below

Answer (score 49):

Make sure you have the correct setup in your `database.yml` file. You should use `template0`, as the error suggests:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: your_db_name
  template: template0
  host: localhost
  ...
```

Comment: I didn't have `template0` in my config, if I place it I get: `PG::Error: ERROR:  permission denied to copy database "template0"
: CREATE DATABASE "my_database_test" ENCODING = 'unicode' TEMPLATE = "template0"`

Comment: that's strange...does it behave the same for the `development` env ?

Comment: Could anyone explain the difference between template0 and template1 and why this works?

Comment: @Jake see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html – everything makes sense after reading this page :-)

Answer (score 16):

If you use Debian, when you install the `postgresql` package it will use your default locale to create the template1 database. If you have not configured your OS to use UTF-8 as a default locale, you will encounter this error.

In addition to the above solutions, if you are on a new installation and have no active databases, you can remove the postgresql package and set your default locale to UTF-8. The advantage of this method is you can omit locale information when creating databases in the future.

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

If you don't see the desired locale, install the locales-all package

```
apt-get install locales-all
```

Then remove postgresql

```
apt-get remove --purge postgresql-<version>
```

Then reinstall or better yet [upgrade to a recent release that isn't in Debian stable](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/).

Comment: I set my default locale to en_US.UTF-8 and followed your instructions to reinstall postgres, and still got the same error after.

Comment: Agree with Simon. What a waste of time :(

Comment: After installing locales, it got worked like magic :)

Comment: Can confirm this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

If your postgres installation is new, and you haven't populated any databases yet, then you can remove your `data` directory and re-run the initdb command with the flag to create databases using UTF-8.

Modify this command to match your postgres installation.  The `-E`/`--encoding` flag tells what character encoding should be the default.  Other character encodings are listed [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/multibyte.html).

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -E UTF8 -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -U postgres
```

It should error and tell you that the `data` directory is not empty.  Follow the instructions and remove the directory, then re-run the command.  (Or, remove the `data` directory before you start, but it's always nice to see the instructions for yourself.)

Answer (score 3):

As for me, I just change the line from `database.yml`:

`encoding: unicode`

to:

`encoding: SQL_ASCII`

just that and it all works.

Comment: This is better than the accepted solution but I'm new to this stuff so I might be not aware of the affects of changing unicode to SQL_ASCII.

Comment: Using SQL_ASCII is not a great default.

Comment: This means any special characters used by non English languages, French accents, even including the degree C symbol will not be able to be stored.   Not a good idea in this day and age.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. My database.yml was like this:-

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: chatapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: chatapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: chatapp_production
  username: chatapp
  password: <%= ENV['CHATAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I added template: template0 to the default settings

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  template: template0
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

And it worked

Comment: Ah, the order is important! `template: template0` *MUST* come before `encoding: unicode` it seems.