# How to fix PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, pg

Every time I try to run

```
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
```

I get this error:

```
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)
HINT:  Use the same encoding as in the template database, or use template0 as template.
: CREATE DATABASE "ruby-getting-started_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:78:in `create_database'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:15:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:276:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"ruby-getting-started_development"}
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)
HINT:  Use the same encoding as in the template database, or use template0 as template.
: CREATE DATABASE "ruby-getting-started_test" ENCODING = 'unicode'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:78:in `create_database'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:15:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:276:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"ruby-getting-started_test"}
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "ruby-getting-started_development" does not exist
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  database "ruby-getting-started_development" does not exist
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is what my database.yml file looks like

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5


development:
  <<: *default
  database: ruby-getting-started_development


  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  #username: ruby-getting-started

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

 # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
 # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
 #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: ruby-getting-started_test


# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
# 
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: ruby-getting-started_production
  username: ruby-getting-started
  password: <%= ENV['RUBY-GETTING-STARTED_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736891/pgerror-error-new-encoding-utf8-is-incompatible). That answer also applies to your question.

Every DB you create in postgres copies template1 DB (it is system DB). The issue you have is that, the encoding of template1 DB is not unicode. So you have two options, (a) change encoding of template1 to unicode or (b) use template0 to create new databases in postgres. template0 is a system database without the encoding information, so it uses the encoding specified. Below solution uses option-b.

Make the below change to your database.yml file:

```
 development:
   <<: *default
   database: ruby-getting-started_development
   template: template0
```

Comment: Ok, I see, but where in the code do I make those edits with the template stuff?

Comment: I don't think I have a file that contains that stuff?

Comment: It seemed to work, but i did still get those errors while it said it migrated

Comment: am I supposed to have some text file with the template stuff? I don't think I installed posture thing