# SQLAlchemy and Postgres UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-unicode

The problem I am facing is same as posted here [SQLAlchemy and UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972363/sqlalchemy-and-unicodedecodeerror). When I fetch results from a table I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The two solutions proposed are using sy.setdefaultencoding('utf8') in python 
and passing additional charset argument to the connection string as follows:

```
conn_str='postgresql+psycopg2://'+str(dbhost)+':' + str(port) + '/postgres?charset=utf8'
```

Both solution seem not to fix the problem. What else can I debug? The table is essentially GIS data for various countries. So the tables have special character.

Comment: Which statement lead this error?

Comment: And what encoding/character-set is your data in?

Comment: @stamaimer: The error occurs when reading the result into python from server.

Comment: @RichardHuxton: The server encoding seems to be in SQL_ASCII. My guess is that is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that encoding is different from server to client. You can verify this issuing these commands:

```
SHOW client_encoding; --Equivalent to: SELECT current_setting('client_encoding');
SHOW server_encoding; --Equivalent to: SELECT current_setting('server_encoding');
```

PostgreSQL automatic converts to client encoding. Probably both are different in your environment. You can configure `client_encoding` by many ways:

- Using `SET` command when open connection in you app: `SET client_encoding = 'UTF-8';`
- Using `set_config` function when open connection in you app: `SELECT set_config('client_encoding', 'UTF-8', true);`
- Configure `PGCLIENTENCODING`environment var in you OS: `export PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8`
- Edit `client_encoding` in postgres config file
- Use `ALTER SYSTEM` (you must refresh config after that with `SELECT pg_reload_conf();`): `ALTER SYSTEM SET client_encoding = 'UTF-8';`

**Update:** Unfortunately it's not possible to enable automatic conversion from SQL_ASCII.

> If the client character set is defined as SQL_ASCII, encoding
>   conversion is disabled, regardless of the server's character set. Just
>   as for the server, use of SQL_ASCII is unwise unless you are working
>   with all-ASCII data.

Quote from [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html).

Comment: Thanks michel. My client encoding is utf8 but server encoding is SQL_ASCII. The mismatch could be reason. I guess I need to recompile the server with UTF8 encoding.

Comment: @Sandeep Before recompile you could try to create a database with right encoding: `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase WITH OWNER = owner_role ENCODING = 'UTF-8' TEMPLATE=TEMPLATE0;` and restore a dump to it.

Comment: Also, for a new database initdb has an option -E UTF8