# Reading VARBINARY via SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, hex, varbinary, memoryview

I am working on a base-datatable with a VARBINARY variable. Now I want to read the table via SQLAlchemy into a pandas dataframe. Going the usual way

*df = pandas.read_sql_query("select key from xxx", engine)*

I get an uninterpretable memoryview as data type. I can convert this via lambda function

*df.key.apply(lambda x: x.tobytes().hex())*

into the desired readable format. But I would like to know if the casting can also be placed directly into the pandas.read_sql_query()-statement:

- via numpy dtypes or maybe
- directly into the SQL-query

Many greetings and best thanks

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5000), yourvarbincolumn, 0) seemed to do the trick within MS-SQL Server. I am guessing call native SQL within SQLAlchemy.. will investigate further. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-sqlalchemy/

Comment: @JGFMK So there is no way to do this using built-in functions from SQLAlchemy? I just tried doing exactly this with a `cast` function but I received `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 6: invalid continuation byte` error.

Comment: @RaulChiarella That might be down to something like the collation of the database. You didn't tag the question with a specific underlying DB, but for SQL Server you can right click on a DB from the Object Explorer in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and Under the General Tab you see the Collation under Maintenance subgroup. On one I use it's SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972363/sqlalchemy-and-unicodedecodeerror

Comment: I see. Thank you. I used `Latin1` and it worked, did `texto_observacao = self.ordem_observacao_binario.decode('latin1')` using a `@property` decorator from SQLAlchemy on the following binary info: `ordem_observacao_binario: Mapped[bytes] = db_sql.Column('TJ_OBSERVA', db_sql.VARBINARY, nullable=True, default=None)`. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you but, thanks to @JGFMK response, I was able to come up with something similar on my program:

1. Defined the property using `Mapped` to convert the value that has a `DATA_TYPE` from the SQL Server.
2. Used a `decode` method on the property, according to the collation my SQL Server is using, going to `Properties > General` on my Database.

This was the result:

```
    # `db_sql.VARBINARY` informs the `DATA_TYPE` from the table field.
    # Mapped does the conversion from table type to python type.
    order_description_binary: Mapped[bytes] = db_sql.Column('TJ_OBSERVA', db_sql.VARBINARY, nullable=True, default=None)

    @property
    def ordem_description(self):
        if self.order_description_binary is not None:
            try:
                description_text = self.order_description_binary .decode('latin1')
                description_text = description_text.replace('\x00', '')
                return description_text
            except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                print(f"Error decoding order_description_binary: {e}")
                return None
        else:
            return None
```

So, in your case you can try using `decode` alongside `replace` on the specific data on your dataframe that has `VARBINARY` type.

Example:

```
df = pandas.read_sql_query("select key from xxx", engine)
df.specific_data.decode('latin1').replace('\x00', '')
```

I believe something like that would work.