# Sqlalchemy - PostgreSQL - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding, sqlalchemy

I am trying to add data from a csv to a PostgreSQL DB using the python lib. sqlalchemy, however I always receive the error: 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 79: invalid start byte' when executing

```
main.drop_duplicates().to_sql('main', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

(full code below).

What I did so far:

- changed in postgresql.conf: client_encoding = utf8
- tried with and without ?charset=utf8" after the database URI, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972363/sqlalchemy-and-unicodedecodeerror)
- added .read_csv(…, encoding_errors="replace") (thanks for the comment!)
- load test data not from a csv, but directly create it in pandas

```
    data = {
        'PROJECT_NUMBER': ['R01HL093399', 'R01HL093399', 'R01HL093399', 'R01HL093399', 'R01HL095924'],
        'PATENT_ID': [8840150, 10022225, 9283301, 10293082, 9556432],
        'PMC_ID': [3132660, 3132660, 3132660, 3132660, 4121125],
        'UNIQUE_ID': ['R01HL093399_8840150_3132660', 'R01HL093399_10022225_3132660', 'R01HL093399_9283301_3132660', 'R01HL093399_10293082_3132660', 'R01HL095924_9556432_4121125']
    }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

- use chardet to 'guess' the encoding of the csv (utf-8)

PostgreSQL db/table creation:

```
CREATE DATABASE Post_db
    WITH 
    OWNER = admin
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    TEMPLATE = template0;

CREATE TABLE main (
    PROJECT_NUMBER VARCHAR(255),
    PRODUCT_ID INT,
    CUSTOMERID INT,
    UNIQUE_ID VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    UNIQUE (PRODUCT_ID),
    UNIQUE (CUSTOMERID)
);
```

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

DATA_PATH = '../../Data/'
CSV_FILE = 'customer_data.csv'

url = URL.create(
    drivername="postgresql",
    username="admin",
    host="localhost",
    database="Post_db",
    password="PASSWORT"
)

engine = create_engine(url)
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, CSV_FILE), encoding='utf8')
df.drop_duplicates().to_sql('main', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Example of CSV file:

```
  PROJECT_NUMBER  PRODUCT_ID  CUSTOMERID                     UNIQUE_ID
0    R01HL093399    8840150  3132660   R01HL093399_8840150_3132660
1    R01HL093399   10022225  3132660  R01HL093399_10022225_3132660
```

Copy paste from CSV file:

```
,PROJECT_NUMBER,PRODUCT_ID,CUSTOMERID,UNIQUE_ID
0,R01HL093399,8840150,3132660,R01HL093399_8840150_3132660
1,R01HL093399,10022225,3132660,R01HL093399_10022225_3132660
2,R01HL093399,9283301,3132660,R01HL093399_9283301_3132660
3,R01HL093399,10293082,3132660,R01HL093399_10293082_3132660
4,R01HL095924,9556432,4121125,R01HL095924_9556432_4121125
```

Even if I try the to_sql command on the rows only, I still get the exact same error as before.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share *full traceback* as well as a part of your data (copy&paste from the `csv` file)…

Comment: Try `.read_csv(…, encoding_errors="replace")` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks; i added the missing info for a reproducable example.

Comment: @gord-thompson Thanks; unfortunately, doesnt make a difference

Comment: I'm betting the issue is the encoding of the CSV file not the database. This `df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, CSV_FILE), encoding='utf8')` is assuming that the file is `UTF8` and that is not helping. FYI, `utf8` is the default for read_csv() anyway. You will need to determine what the file encoding is.

Comment: @adrian-klaver thanks for the suggestion. While I agree, and also thought it might be caused by the encoding of the csv, even when loading data directly into a pandas dataframe, I still get the exact same error... (+ checked encoding in notepad++ & using the chardet lib.)

Comment: How did you get the data into the dataframe, copy and paste from somewhere else?

Comment: Even if you copy that hard coded data back into your code and run it you still get the exception?  What versions of pandas, python and sqlalchemy are you using?  Can you include more of a traceback?  This seems like maybe it has nothing to do with the actual data.  Maybe you or something in the tool chain is double decoding/encoding or something.

Comment: I agree that this question really needs (1) A [mcve] that uses a manually-created DataFrame, thus eliminating the `.read_csv()`, (2) version information for all components, and (3) a complete stack trace.